# Can I attach an authentication cookie for a different site from my .NET Core web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, powerbi

We have a .NET Core web application with an AngularJS SPA front-end.  We also have a Power BI Report Server with a few dozen Paginated Reports (SSRS).  We would like for the web app users to be able to view/save/print the reports from the web app, without having to authenticate again into the Power BI Report Server.  We also don't want to maintain two user lists (one for the web app, and one for the PBIRS).  I have been told that they want us to use a single service account for PBIRS, and have the web app authenticate in to PBIRS, and serve up the reports to the user.

Unfortunately, Microsoft's official SSRS Report Viewer control (which allows you to enter authentication info), only supports Web Forms, which is not compatible with .NET Core.  I have tried a few .NET Core wrappers for it, but I was not able to get them working.

Then I had another idea.  Can I have my .NET code create a client, authenticate into PBIRS, and maybe get an authentication cookie, then somehow attach that cookie to the user's browser, so that if the user goes directly to the PBIRS, the cookie is valid and they are authenticated in as the service account user?  How can I do this?

These two servers might be in different subdomains, but I think they will be in the same domain.  I need to verify this.  I think it might not be possible at all if they are on different domains, correct?